# Angular, ngrx-store-localstorage: Map stored in localstorage cannot be rehydrated

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

I've been struggling with loading `Map` from localstorage couple of days. A `Map` is created in action reducer and it's successfully serialized and saved into localstorage. The problem becomes with loading it on refresh (flag `rehydrate` is set to `true`). Seems like the `Map` is successfully deserialized, but it's not existing in the new state after `@ngrx/store/init` action (only after refresh), there is just `{}` (empty object) instead. I'm also wondering why it's `null` (which is correct) after first init (page load; with empty localstorage) and `{}` after other init (refresh).

I've tried also `replacer` and `reviver` functions

> - replacer: A replacer function as specified in the JSON.stringify documentation.
> - reviver: A reviver function as specified in the JSON.parse documentation.

But without success.

I created [Stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dbjopn?file=src/store/reducers/index.ts).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your issue is that deepmerge package, [used](https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage/blob/master/projects/lib/src/lib/index.ts#L227) by default for restoring data, [do not support Map and Set](https://github.com/TehShrike/deepmerge/issues/204)

In order to fix it you need to

1. replace deep merge with [deepmerge-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge-ts)
2. add `mergeReducer` to `ngrx-store-localstorage` config

Here is [the updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cd3pir?file=src%2Fstore%2Freducers%2Findex.ts)

```
import { deepmerge } from "deepmerge-ts";

const INIT_ACTION = '@ngrx/store/init';
const UPDATE_ACTION = '@ngrx/store/update-reducers';

export function localStorageSyncReducer(
    reducer: ActionReducer<any>
  ): ActionReducer<any> {
    return localStorageSync({
      keys: [
        {
          map: {
            serialize: (map) => Array.from(map.entries()),
            deserialize: (map) => new Map(map),
          },
        },
      ],
      rehydrate: true,
      mergeReducer(state, rehydratedState, action) {
        if ((action.type === INIT_ACTION || action.type === UPDATE_ACTION) && rehydratedState) {
            state = deepmerge(state, rehydratedState);
        }
    
        return state;
      },
      removeOnUndefined: true,
      restoreDates: true,
    })(reducer);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried it myself I saw the same thing.
What weird is that there's no issue on github about this. So I'm not sure if this is a workaround or a solution.

Here in the doc, you can see:

> mergeReducer (optional) (state: any, rehydratedState: any, action: any) => any: Defines the reducer to use to merge the rehydrated state from storage with the state from the ngrx store. If unspecified, defaults to performing a full deepmerge on an INIT_ACTION or an UPDATE_ACTION.

So the `rehydratedState` is parsed as a separated state and then being merged with the original state. Maybe this is the reason why we always see `{}` - the merged state.

To overcome this, I declare the mergeReducer to return the rehydratedState directly

```
return localStorageSync({
    keys: [
      ...
    ],
    ...
    mergeReducer: (state: any, rehydratedState: any, action: any) => {
      return rehydratedState;
    }
  })(reducer);
```

I guess with more custom state values, you also need to merge it yourself here in this function.